# Find a specific folder in all remote and local GIT branches

Tags: linux, git, smartgit

I have few hundreds of remote and local branches.  I wonder whether there is a command to help me find a folder with a specific name in all branches.

My git version is 1.8.3.1.  I also have smartgit installed if it matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pull` all branches and use `find` command to find the directory whether it is present or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will output all refs (local and remotes) that point to a commit which contains the path specified in the variable `SEARCH_PATH`

```
SEARCH_PATH="somePath"

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads refs/remotes | 
   while read ref
      do 
         if [[ `git ls-tree -r --name-only $ref` =~ "$SEARCH_PATH" ]] ; then                 
           echo $ref; 
         fi
   done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run following to list your required folders/files

`` for line in `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads`;
do
    git ls-tree -r $line | grep 'file_regex'
done ``

Comment: The above runs for refs/heads , you can also add refs/remotes for searching the remote branches